# script works in php 7 but not php 5

Tags: php, json, datatables, php-5.3, php-7

This code works in `php 7` (localhost) but not `php 5` (isp). It converts a delimited text file to a `json` file for use with `dataTables`.

source:

```
 6590|07/19/2003|RCC Sat. Open|C11|Nikolayev, Igor (FM)|2402|Gonzalez, Jose|2131|1-0|
```

Desired result:

```
 {"data":[
 {"game":"6624","Date":"11/01/2003","Event":"RCC Sat. Open","ECO":"C65","White":"Liman, Christ","WhiteElo":"1729","Black":"Nikolayev, Igor (FM)","BlackElo":"2408","Result":"0-1"},
....
]}
```

How come?

```
<?php

$text = file('games.txt'); $count = count($text); arsort($text);

$X = 0;

$fp = fopen("games.json", "w");

fwrite ($fp, "{"); fwrite ($fp, '"data":['); 

foreach($text as $line) {$token = explode("|", $line); 

$game = $token[0]; $date = $token[1]; $event = $token[2]; $eco = $token[3]; $white = $token[4];
$white_rating = $token[5]; $black = $token[6]; $black_rating = $token[7]; $result = $token[8];

  fwrite ($fp, "\n");
  fwrite ($fp,'{');  

  fwrite ($fp, '"game":"'.$game.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"Date":"'.$date.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"Event":"'.$event.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"ECO":"'.$eco.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"White":"'.$white.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"WhiteElo":"'.$white_rating.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"Black":"'.$black.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"BlackElo":"'.$black_rating.'",'); 
  fwrite ($fp, '"Result":"'.$result.'"'); 

  $X++;

  fwrite ($fp, '}');
  if ( $X <= $count-1 ) {fwrite ($fp, ',');}

  }

  fwrite ($fp, "]"); 

  fwrite ($fp, "}"); 

  fclose($fp);

  header('Location:pgn_assistant.php');
  ?>
```

Comment: It is not advisable to create your own JSON conversion method when `json_encode` exists natively. Also are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I will investigate json_encode shortly.

Comment: On the face of it I don't see anything incompatible with PHP 5.6. Are your permissions correct on the files you are attempting to read and write? Alternatively are they in the correct locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the PHP Documentation you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

It is native way to encode an array or any object implementing `\JsonSerializable` into json string.

```
file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($data));
```